# Clean way to pass parameters between JavaScript events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have values I would like to keep in memory when certain events fire, like when a user is dragging and I want to save the element index. The value is needed when another event might fire. I don't know if it will ever fire.

I am using global variables to keep these values around. It seems there are better ways to do this like putting these values in an object with a namespace. Benefits? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Namespace is always good. But it depends on your "application". If you are creating this only for your site, i.e. you control the environment, then you could live with globals.

Comment: Namespaced variables are still global, just confined...

Answer (score 4):

My alltime favorite is currying variables into event handlers. Curry is a function prototype and when called on a function it will return a version of the function with preset arguments:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function curry() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function curryed() {
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};

node.addEventListener('mousedown', handler.curry(var1,var2,etc));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could bind the data to a parent element that is a relevant container for each value. So for example, say you have a #dragAndDropContainer, in which there are many drag and droppable items, then as soon as a drag event fires (i.e. a drag begins), you could (in jQuery), execute:

```
$('#dragAndDropContainer').data('lastDragged', $(this).attr('id'));
```

And then just query `$('#dragAndDropContainer').data('lastDragged')` every time you need to.

Answer (score 1):

I like davin's solution, but here is an alternative if that doesn't suit you. You can create a closure around the event handler like so:

```
var data = { x: 1, y: 2 };
var handler = function() {
  console.log(data);
}

if (node.addEventListener) {
  node.addEventListener('mousedown', handler, false);
} else {
  node.attachEvent('onmousedown', handler);
}
```

Comment: hehe, i think you meant attachEvent, although we could try to attackEvent as well :)

Comment: @davin That is the best typeo I've made in a long time. I almost hate to fix it.

Comment: i feel your pain. although my comment will perpetuate its memory

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using Function.bind (sometimes known as curry): You can control the scope of your shared variable. Here's some jQuery pseudo-code demonstrating it. Shared is accessible to those two handlers and nobody else.

```
$(function(){
  var shared = {a:1, b:2};
   $('#id-1').click(function() {
      alert(shared.a);
   });

   $('#id-2').click(function() {
      alert(shared.b);
   });
});
```

If you're writing jQuery procedural code, the closure approach is much simpler. Since most everything I write is an object, I'd rather not get into too many levels of inner closures, so I prefer to setup a handler with binding/currying (like Martin's example) if a handler needs access to shared variables.